# Integration of a function twice, getting rid of derivation

Tags: integration

I encounter a proof and do not understand well or couldn't figure out some steps, and need to understand all steps. The goal is to find u(v) function from derivations.
$$ u(0)=0 \space \space \text{and} \space \space u'(1) =0 \space \text{are known}$$

\begin{equation} 0 = \frac{dG[h(v;u)]}{dv} + u''(v) \end{equation}
Integrating this gives:
$$ u'(v)=\bar{G}[h(v;u)]$$
Then integrating this with respect to v and using $ u(0)=0 $
with $\textbf{some mathematical manipulation}$, we obtain
$$ u(v)= v\bar{G}[h(v;u)] + \int_0^v z dG[h(v;u)] $$

I assume that $\bar{G}[h(v;u)]=G[h(v;u)]+c $ and c is a constant, but couldn't figure out about getting rid of the first derivative, I mean the last step. Can someone explain to me these manipulation.

thanks

Comment: Have you studied Differential Equations yet?

Comment: I suppose we might be able to treat this weird conglomeration $G[h(v; u)]$ as simple function $g(v, u)$. But in your final integral, you introduce a new element $z$ that has no connection defined defined with anything else. Without knowing what $z$ is, the best we can tell you is what definition of $z$ will make the equation true.

Comment: That is the problem for me too, they don't mention anywhere else about that and give this final result. I thought maybe I am missing something maybe, but I guess I am not.